# Replace the phone numbers not having exactly 10 digits

Tags: r

How to replace the phone numbers not having exactly 10 digits with NA

```
c(99887766, 998877665521, 9897932453)
```

Expected output:

```
NA, NA, 9897932453
```

Answer (score 4):

We create a logical vector using `nchar` and assign those not having 10 characters as NA

```
v1[nchar(v1) != 10] <- NA
v1
#[1]         NA         NA 9897932453
```

---

Or another option is

```
v1[!grepl('^.{10}$', v1)] <- NA
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c(99887766, 998877665521, 9897932453)
```

Comment: Thank you. I had used the same nchar command and was wondering whether using character command to count numeric digits is the right way or not.

Comment: It's the most readable and straightforward way, and I think it makes the most conceptual sense given you're really counting symbols and not comparing numbers. For efficiency maybe Roland's solution (in his PS, not with log transformation) is faster as it uses `is.na` and doesn't convert types.

Answer (score 3):

Use simple maths. We know that `log10(1000000000)` is 9 and that `log10(10000000000)` is 10. Thus:

```
v1 <- c(99887766, 998877665521, 9897932453)
is.na(v1) <- log10(v1) >= 10 | log10(v1) < 9
v1
#[1]         NA         NA 9897932453
```

I assume that the input won't have decimal fractions.

PS: You don't even need the log. You could also just compare with 1e9 and 1e10.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use function `is.na<-`.
Like the help page says, `value` is an index vector into the argument of the function. In this case, a logical index.

```
v1 <- c(99887766, 998877665521, 9897932453)

is.na(v1) <- nchar(v1) != 10
v1
#[1]         NA         NA 9897932453
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ifelse()` :

```
phones <- c(99887766, 998877665521, 9897932453)

ifelse(nchar(phones) != 10, NA, phones)

[1]         NA         NA 9897932453
```